# Unable to increase partition size with subsequent blocking partition

Tags: macos, bootcamp, disk-utility, partition

[image]

I can't make my main Macintosh HD partition bigger. It's limited by the partition in the middle, which seems to be frozen, I can't move it down to make space for my main partition. Also I can't seem to delete it. The format of disk0s4 is Mac OS Extended (Journaled).

Some background, I created a partition to experiment with bootcamp to use windows. Once done I deleted that new partition, it became a no-man's land that neither partition can claim.

As a seperate issue, boot camp assistant has been giving me this error:
[image]

Anyone has any ideas? Much appreciated!

The closest problem I've found is here, this is a FAT partition.
[Unable to increase Macintosh HD partition size with data in a subsequent partition](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/22140/unable-to-increase-macintosh-hd-partition-size-with-data-in-a-subsequent-partiti)

Comment: Have you tried using Disk Utility in Recovery Mode? To use Recovery Mode, hold down *⌘ + R* during boot. Press and hold these keys until the Apple logo appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [iPartition](https://coriolis-systems.com)

For all my partitioning, I use and recommend iPartition. It will allow you to resize partitions without deleting any data. It will automatically move partitions if necessary to allow resizing into free space that is located after the partition.

> iPartition’s ability to automatically rearrange your existing partitions when necessary, makes iPartition the easiest partitioning tool that you’ll ever use.
>
> [image]

Answer (score 1):

## [GParted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/download.php)

iPartition has a non-functional demo mode, which is quite misleading. If you don't want to pay the $50 for it, the [GParted live CD/USB](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/download.php) is a good Free alternative.

It can't resize HFS+ partitions [according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GParted#Supported_features) but it can copy and move them, and then you should be able to resize using the built-in Disk Utility.

Answer (score 0):

If you can format the blank space as MS-DOS, then Bootcamp Assistant should give you the option to "Remove Windows 7", and it should resize all your partitions back for you automatically.

The error you're getting is because it doesn't see a Windows installation to remove, and it doesn't support creating a new Windows installation in the situation you have.